# ror how to route to books/id/1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

I have books as resource and id, ean, isbn are its properties.
I want it to be accessed as `books/id/1` or `books/isbn/1212100000` or `books/ean/1313911`

In my routes.rb, I have written following.

```
   resources :books do
        collection do
            get 'isbn'
            get 'ean'
            get 'id'
        end
    end
```

But, when I try to access l`ocalhost:3000/books/id/1`,
it gives....
No route matches "`/books/id/1`"

I can access `localhost:3000/books/id` though.
This means that I need to write separate mapping in routes.rb but then what is the use of resource declaration?

can anyone suggest me to do this without writing explicit mappings.

Answer (score 2):

Collection routes are expected to return multiple results, hence dont have an id parameter. if you want id, use member routes, eg:

```
resources :books do
    member do
        get 'isbn'
        get 'ean'
        get 'id'
    end
end
```

Comment: adding member routes also do not work as it supports routes of format books/1/id. However, I need route of the format books/id/1.

Comment: Then you should use match. But that url scheme isnt very RESTful.

Comment: All I want is to search any table not only by its id but by other attributes also. but declaring that table as resource not helping me to do it. match is always the option but I would not like to use it as I was looking for some ways to do it with resource. I just wonder if no one has ever come across such a requirement?

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
match ':controller/:action/:id/'
```

to your routes.rb, near the end.

Comment: Why would you introduce a catchall for something so simple?

Comment: I can always add that. The question however is, how do i do this with rails resource way? The question is very simple. How can i get attributes of any database table with their corresponding values by URL routes? especially when I have declared that particular table as resource.